# SSIS Conditional Split - multiple conditions per output

Tags: ssis, split, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use the conditional split to score a row based on 3 criteria?

I'd rather not create a tree if I can avoid it

Essentially to do something like this (note all outputs are from a single conditional split)

**Output 1** (Score 0)
Field1 == 0 && Field2 == 0 && Field3 == 0

**Output 2** (Score 1)
(Try1 == 1 && Try2 == 0 && Try3 == 0)||
(Try1 == 0 && Try2 == 1 && Try3 == 0)||
(Try1 == 0 && Try2 == 0 && Try3 == 1)

**Output 3** (Score 2)
(Field1 == 1 && Field2 == 1 && Field3 == 0)||
(Field1 == 1 && Field2 == 0 && Field3 == 1)||
(Field1 == 0 && Field2 == 1 && Field3 == 1)

**Output 4** (Score 3)
Field1 == 1 && Field2 == 1 && Field3 == 1

Of course outputs 1 and 4 are easy to achieve but can I create outputs 2 and 3 without creating a tree system of conditional splits to assess each try on each row?

Thanks very much

Comment: Yes. (I'm not 100% sure what you mean by tree system)

Comment: Are these bit/booleans or integers? If Integer, are they only ever 1 or 0? I assume on Output 2, `Try1` is `Field1`?

Comment: @BI DUDE - I mean I can check the first field, then the 2nd this would need to checks though, 1 for a positive result for the 1st and 1 for a negative - and then 4 after that for the 3rd check creating a tree looking system. Does that make sense?

Comment: @billinkc - This is actually a web friendly version, each field will be a string in the production version however the logic remains the same - Yes try is field, forgot to change that one haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the Conditional Split shape put in a Derived Column shape which creates a new column called Score with the following expression:

```
(DT_I4)[Field1] + (DT_I4)[Field2] + (DT_I4)[Field3]
```

Then in your Conditional Split the four branches compare the Score column like so:

```
Score == 0
Score == 1
Score == 2
Score == 3
```

Comment: That's the one. Thanks very much, that has worked just as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

General things to note.

A Conditional Split will evaluate options in order. So if you define Output 1 and Output 4 streams first, then you don't have to worry about the tree of conditional splits, assuming I understood what you meant by that

If these are integers, you could just use math to identify the total score.

```
Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4 == 0

Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4 == 1

Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4 == 2

Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4 == 3
```

Or just compute a new column called TotalScore and make it `TotalScore == 0` etc

If it's boolean, then there's probably some truth table/logic operation I've long forgotten that would simplify this.

Comment: Unfortunately they are all strings so I need to code for each combination of possibilities rather than adding them together.

Comment: How does them being strings force you to look for the permutations? Especially since you accepted an answer that adds them together as I proposed

Comment: because if they were integers or boolean I could get to a point where I could simply add them together to get my score, as they are strings I need to tell the split explicitly what stings count as a 'points' and what does not and then check for which ones were met. The answer I accepted suggested creating a derived column which did have a 1 or a 0 so I could simply add up. I had not thought of the derived column and without that the only option was to check the live data against each possible mix of the 3 strings to get the scores.